# How to install and use modules in SilverStripe

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

Using SilverStripe I want to use multi-select drop down on my page.

How can I install and use modules to do this?

Comment: Could you please give us little better description on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General approach of installing a module in SilverStripe:

- Prerequisite: As always, back up your database.
- Log into your site as admin. I'm always doing this first, in case any changes prohibit a log in later on (normally if you change your existing code, but logging in first never hurts).
- Unpack the module and put it into your installation's base folder (where `sapphire`, `cms`, `mysite`,... are).
- Make sure the folder is named correctly, this should be described in the download. If there is no specific description, leave the name as it is after unpacking. There shouldn't be a version number in the folder name.
- Go to `http://yoursite.com/dev/build?flush=all` - that will sync your database with your code.
- You're good to use the module...

Comment: I have silverstripe 3.1.13 and have unzziped the SortableGridField module (Requirements: SilverStripe 3.0.x, 3.1.x, 3.2.x ) to the destination folder SortableGridField in the directory containing assets,cmd,framework etc. The problem I am having is that when doing the /dev/build?flush=all silverstripe will not pick up the module and it doesn't rebuild the database. Is there anything I need to have in mind that I am missing? Thanks Module link [link](https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/SortableGridField#installation)

Comment: If the installation docs don't work for you, I'd open up an issue on GitHub where you can debug this further. Looks good to me, given that you don't have a typo in `SortableGridField` and you have a `_config.php` file right in that folder.